# Error in opencv function in .exe file but not in debug nor release

Tags: c++, opencv

One more time, I want to ask for your help after long and unfruitful researches.
I have developped an app using OpenCV which works very well is Visual Studio in debug and release mode.

I tried to deploy it, but i get a fatal error when I start the .exe. By using a log file and doing tests, I figured out the problem was in function cv::resize in the following code :

```
Mat logo = imread("lena.png");
cv::resize(logo, logo, Size(), 0.55, 0.55, INTER_CUBIC);
```

I found very weird that i can call cv::imread (and cv::Mat) without throwing exception but not resize.

If I try to run the .exe created by the compilation in release mode, i get the following errod code : 0xc000007b.

I read it could be a problem of compatibility between 32/64-bits dll, without being able to solve it. I try to build a 64-bits appplication. The path for opencv lib is define like this : C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib

Thank you for your help,

Valentin B

Comment: what's the error? if `imread` is not able to read the image (wrong path), then `resize` will crash

Comment: If you run appplication in release or debug mode in VS, VS studio just runs the exe that has just been built. So if you have a problem with exe later on, I suppose that it must be missing dll. Please write the complete error or any other info which is returned.

Comment: The error code `0xc000007b` usually means that you're loading the DLL with a different architecture. Be sure that in your PATH you have the path `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin` (note also **bin** instead of **lib**), and you don't have any other path to other OpenCV versions

Comment: thank you all for your help, it was indeed that simple, the .exe was not created in the same folder than the project so, it could not find the image.
I am surprised that imread doesn't throw any explicit exception when it fails to find the image. Printing the exception only gave me "85".
Miki, If you can post your comment as an answer i can select it and close the subject. Thank you all.